# How to unlock Oracle apex cloud workspace account?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I was using Oracle apex cloud account on 
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex

Unfortunately my workspace account got locked. As I don't know the password of admin user of the workspace given by Oracle that's why I am unable to unlock my account is there any way to unlock that account? I tried to reset the password but that was of no use because it continuously giving message that the account is locked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down on that page and click "Who do I contact for help?", it says for locked accounts you should email oracle-application-express_ww@oracle.com

Comment: How long ago did you email them? You might need to be patient.

Comment: If you have not accessed your workspace for a few months, they purge it.  Not sure if you'd get a different error in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to database and the box it runs on? When I first provisioned Oracle Integration Cloud I had no knowledge of the password for the internal workspaces admin account. I simply ran

```
SQLPLUS /NOLOG 
SQL> CONNECT SYS AS SYSDBA 
SQL> @APXCHPWD
```

It will let you set a new password for the admin account on the internal workspace, at which point you can reset your password for this particular user in this particular workspace

Answer (score 0):

You must go on Oracle Cloud > Database Actions > Database Users
There you will see your account locked (orange), click on Edit
Your account seems not locked there => click to lock :-) => Apply
Click Edit again and unlock the account + Apply => it turn to green (unlocked)